# Difference in Time Using mktime function in linux

Tags: linux, utc, epoch, mktime

Let us say I have 2 different input times. Time-1  is `2013-10-01-00-00-00` and Time-2 is `2000-01-01-12-00-00`.

I have populated the above two times into `struct tm` structures. I have used `mktime` and passed the 2 structures and got two different values of `type time_t`. Let us they are Time_1 and Time_2 respectively.

Now if I take the difference of Time_1 and Time_2 ,

1. Does it include the elapsed seconds between the 2 input times Time-1
   and Time-2 ?
2. Does the function internally take care of extra second for leap
   years ?
3. To Get The Actual Difference in terms of UTC , do I need to
   add/subtract leap years ?

Answer (score 0):

A leap year is a year with an extra day in it. All of the Posix time functions handle these perfectly.

There are also "leap seconds" which are inserted into or deleted from UTC from time to time by the International Earth Rotation and Reference Systems Service. None of the Posix time functions are aware of leap-seconds.

So if you care about leap seconds, you need to account for them yourself. If you're only interested in what are commonly called leap years, no worries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But Sir can you post any official link claiming that the posix time functions handle leap years.

Comment: The mktime converts a local time into the number of seconds from Epoch. (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15). In order for that to be correct, it must take leap years into account. If it didn't, it would compute the incorrect number of seconds since epoch. Obviously, the difference between two "seconds since epoch" values is the number of seconds between the two values.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. Now one more doubt. What is the resolution of per second count in the above function ? How the O/S arrives at the per second count ? If the system is synchronized to a NTP server , does it have any impact on the per second count ?

Comment: @Soumajit: the resolution is not defined, but it is seconds on all major OS's. How the OS manages to keep track of the time is also not standardized, but NTP servers are common. Usually the OS synchronizes with the time server by "smearing" the drift: it adds or subtracts a tiny amount to each second until the times are in synch again. Abrupt changes in the system clock can cause time to appear to go backwards, and clumsy sysadmins can make abrupt changes. However, none of that will affect the acuracy of subtracting one fully specified time from another.

Comment: Thanks once again Sir. Suppose I have 2 different linux ( RHEL ) systems where I am observing the difference in Time-1 and Time-2 as mentioned in the earlier Question. Now let us assume one of the system is not synchronized to NTP. But other system is synchronized to NTP server. Does the difference in seconds between the 2 systems will vary ? How to determine what is the resolution per second is being used by the posix function ( In this case mktime ) I am using for computation ?

Comment: @Soumajit: mktime turns a *specified* time into an offset from epoch. It has nothing to do with the actual time. So it has nothing to do with NTP. As for resolution, difftime() always gives you the difference between two time_t's as a `double` in seconds. I don't know any way of finding out whether the time value changes every second (other than observing it) but as far as I know it does on every OS in common use. `time_t` could, in theory, have more resolution than a second (difftime() still has to work), but it doesn't and I'm not sure that Posix allows it to any more.

Comment: Thanks once again Sir. Now I l slightly divert the discussion. What are the  advantages we get if our system is synchronized to NTP against being stand alone ? Is it only related to the accuracy of the current time with respect to GPS/UTC ? It has nothing to do with internal time related computation ?

Comment: @Soumajit: You don't need to know the current time to figure out the difference between April and October any more than you need to know exactly where you're standing to figure out the distance between Paris and London. Relativity theory really doesn't come into play here.

Comment: Thank You Sir. But my question was different. My point was what are the advantages of NTP based time synchronization against absent of it.

Comment: @Soumajit: you should probably ask a different question, then. With respect to calendric computations, NTP synchronization is irrelevant, since it only has to do with synchronizing walltime.